# JPA Entity Bulk Delete not working

Tags: java, jpa

I have three related entities

```
public class EntityA
{
private Long id;
}


public class EntityB
{
private Long id;
private EntityA entityA;
private EntityC entityC;

}

public class EntityC
{
private Long id;
}
```

`Query query = persistenceManager.createNamedQuery("DELETE FROM EntityB a WHERE a.entityA = :entityA AND a.entityC.id in :entityCList");
query.setParameter("entityA", entityAObj);
query.setParameter("entityCList", entityCList);
query.executeUpdate();`

I am using MySQL database. The parameter `:entityCList` is an `ArrayList` of `entityC ids` i.e. `List<Long> entityCList` and `:entityA` is an Object of `EntityA`.

When i ran the delete query above, the records did not delete from the database and it did not throw an exception. What could be wrong with the query.

Comment: If you're using Hibernate, its doc explicitely says that joins can't be used in the where clause: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#batch-direct

Comment: @JB Nizet You are right. I am using hibernate i guess that is exactly the issue. Is there any workarounds to this?

Answer (score 1):

What was the SQL generated?

Try comparing entityC to a list of EntityC objects instead of ids.

Or, try using a sub-select, instead of a join.

Comment: I have tried comparing objects, i noticed a strange thing. It removes some and don't remove some still no error.

`Query query = persistenceManager.createNamedQuery("DELETE FROM EntityB a WHERE a.entityA = :entityA AND a.entityC in :entityCList")`. What do you think should be the problem? My last solution is to call an entity remove on each entity.